# Android wear can´t send message to phone

Tags: android, wear-os, google-datalayer, wearables

I been following [this tutorial](https://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync.html#first-wearable-message) to send a message from an Android wear to an Android phone, but it is not working. This is my code:

**Wear**

To start with the Minifest, I implemented the google play services metadata, like this:

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Second of all, I initialize the GoogleApiClient, like this:

```
googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

Then, I implement all the methods required from the interfaces: GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks and
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        System.out.println("SESSION CONNECTED");
    }

    // Disconnect from the data layer when the Activity stops
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (null != googleClient && googleClient.isConnected()) {
            googleClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      googleClient.connect();
   }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        System.out.println("FAILED TO CONNECT: "+connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }
```

Finally I implement the send the text to the phone:

```
 NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleClient).await();
        for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
            MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleClient, node.getId(), path, message.getBytes()).await();
            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                System.out.println("Message: {" + message + "} sent to: " + node.getDisplayName());
            }
            else {
                // Log an error
               System.out.println("ERROR: failed to send Message");
            }
        }
```

The thing is that it seems to work (I get the ""SESSION CONNECTED" string when I start the wear), but it can´t find any paired devices to send the string to, since the list of nodes is empty. Could it be a problem this the simulator? Both the phone and the wear may not be sycronized, and thus is why they can´t find each other.

**Phone**

Just to show the hole example, I´m also including the phone part:

Manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".utils.ListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"
                tools:ignore="WearableBindListener" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

ListenerService

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals("/message_path")) {
        final String message = new String(messageEvent.getData());
        System.out.println("Message path received on watch is: " + messageEvent.getPath());
        System.out.println("Message received on watch is: " + message);
    }
    else {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nevermind, it was a problem with the emulator, that they were not sycned. Just trying out with the real devices and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was that the application on the phone and the application on the watch were signed with different certificates, although they had the same appid